# Macro or add-in to help moving hard-coded strings into an MFC .rc file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, internationalization, automation, string-table

I am working on internationalizing an old MFC project and I have many thousands of hard-coded strings to move into the string table.  I'm looking for a macro, add-in, or some information on creating a macro, add-in, or wizard that would allow me to semi-automate the process.  I would like to be able to highlight a string, right-click and select something like "move to resource" and have the string added to the string table for the project.  Something customizable would be great such that I could edit the identifier created and have the tool replace the hard-coded string in the code with a look up function (that I provide the name of).  I searched for a few days and can't find anything like this.  Does anyone know of a tool already in existence, or can provide some info on what VS extensiblity classes I can use to write one?  I am using VS2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at http://www.lingobit.com/products/hardcoded_string_extraction.html ? This is the only product I know of that does this. It's a hairy problem because there are so many corner cases.